# Avoid warning 'Unreferenced Formal Parameter'

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a super class like this:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void Function(int param);
};

void Parent::Function(int param)
{
    std::cout << param << std::endl;
}
```

..and a sub-class like this:

```
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void Function(int param);
};

void Child::Function(int param)
{
    ;//Do nothing
}
```

When I compile the sub-class .cpp file, I get this error

```
warning C4100: 'param' : unreferenced formal parameter
```

As a practice, we used to treat warnings as errors. How to avoid the above warning?

Thanks.

Comment: Use boost::ignore_unused(param) http://stackoverflow.com/a/24310846/888576

Answer (score 106, accepted):

In C++ you don't have to give a parameter that you aren't using a name so you can just do this:

```
void Child::Function(int)
{
    //Do nothing
}
```

You may wish to keep the parameter name in the declaration in the header file by way of documentation, though. The empty statement (`;`) is also unnecessary.

Comment: @Charles..If the function is inline, is it legal to do like this? `class Child : public Parent { public: void Function(int /*param*/ = 0, int param2 = 0) { std::cout << param2 << std::endl; } };`

Comment: You mean have a nameless parameter with a default value. I'm not 100% sure but I think that it is legal. I don't know of any reason why not in any case.

Comment: @bdhar: Note that it is dangerous to provide default parameters at different levels of the hierarchy unless your default values coincide. The problem you can get is that calling the same function from two contexts might end up calling the same final overrider with different default values: `struct base { virtual void f( int i = 0); }; struct derived : base { virtual void f( int i = 5 ); }; int main() { derived d; base & b = d; d.f() /* D::f(5) */; b.f(); /* D::f(0) */ }`

Comment: +1 because now I finally know a scenario where it makes sense to omit the name.

Comment: Thanks, David.. Let me take care of the conditions :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. +1 for the clever workaround!

Comment: Event though the implementation may not need the parameter, what if you need to debug that call and watch the value?

Answer (score 33):

I prefer using a macro, as it tells not only the compiler my intention, but other maintainers of the code, and it's searchable later on.

The method of commenting out the argument name can easily be missed by people unfamiliar with the code (or me 6 months later).

However, it's a style-issue, neither method is "better" or more optimal with regards to code generated, performance or robustness.  To me, the deciding factor is informing others of my intent through a standardized system.  Omitting the parameter name and putting in a comment would work equally well:

```
void CFooBar::OnLvnItemchanged(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pNMHDR);
```

Alternatively:

```
void CFooBar::OnLvnItemchanged(NMHDR* /* pNMHDR */, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    // Not using: pNMHDR
```

I would say that the worst solution is suppressing the warning message; that that will affect your entire file or project, and you'll lose the knowledge that maybe you've missed something.  At least by adding the macro, or commenting out the argument name, you've told others that you've made a conscious decision to not use this argument and that it's not a mistake.

The Windows SDK in WinNT.h defines `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER()` along with `DBG_UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER()` and `DBG_UNREFERENCED_LOCAL_VARIABLE()`.  They all evaluate to the same thing, but the difference is that DBG_UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER() is used when you are starting out and expect to use the parameter when the code is more complete.  When you are sure you'll never use the parameter, use the UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER() version.

The Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) have a similar convention, with the shorter `UNUSED()` and `UNUSED_ALWAYS()` macros.

Pick a style and stick with it.  That way later on you can search for "`DBG_UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER`" in your code and find any instances of where you expected to use a argument, but didn't.  By adopting a consistent style, and habitually using it, you'll make it easier for other and yourself later on.

Comment: Commenting the parameter name is definitely the best practice in my opinion, and also the most readable.

Comment: @DavidKirby you can not us e commented-out name if you have ifdef inside of function which make parameter used or not depending on the define.

Comment: The commented out parameter should be NMHDR* /* pNMHDR */ not NMHDR /* *pNMHDR */ as above, which is a bug that changes the function signature. More generally, don't put a space between the type and the star: NMHDR* pNMHDR

Answer (score 21):

Another technique that you can use if you want to keep the parameter name is to cast to void:

```
void Child::Function(int param)
{
    (void)param;   //Do nothing
}
```

Comment: That's OK for built-in types like int, but if the parameter is a reference to an incomplete type, casting it to void introduces a need for the full definition of the type to be seen where no such need may have existed before.

Comment: This is the solution for the C langage, so useful.

Comment: Qt's Q_UNUSED macro is a slightly more fancy version of this.

Answer (score 12):

As @Charles Bailey mentioned, you can skip the parameter name.

However, in certain scenarios, you need the parameter name, since in debug builds you are calling an `ASSERT()` on it, but on retail builds it's a `nop`. For those scenarios there's a handy macros (at least in VC++ :-)) `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER()`, which is defined like this:

```
#define UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(x) x
```

Note that the simple cast @R Samuel Klatchko posted also works, but I personally find it more readable if the code is explicit that this is an unreferenced parameter vs. simple unexplained cast like that.

Comment: Hiding behind a macro is a good idea (you are right that it's clearer then my example).  That said, you should probably add the cast to your macro or you may get a warning (on g++ 4.2.1, I get `warning: statement has no effect`)

Comment: You could define ASSERT(param) for non-debug build with (void)param. Your UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER suggests that's not referenced at all. But it can be referenced -- in ASSERT.

Answer (score 8):

Since C++17 you also can use [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) to avoid such warnings:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void Function([[maybe_unused]] int param);
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Pragma works nicely too since it's clear you are using VS. This warning has a very high noise to benefit ratio, given that unreferenced parameters are very common in callback interfaces and derived methods. Even teams within Microsoft Windows who use W4 have become tired of its pointlessness (would be more suitable for /Wall) and simply added to their project:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4100)
```

If you want to alleviate the warning for just a block of code, surround it with:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4100)
void SomeCallbackOrOverride(int x, float y) { }
#pragma warning(pop)
```

The practice of leaving out the parameter name has the downside in the debugger that you can't easily inspect by name nor add it to the watch (becomes confused if you have more than one unreferenced parameter), and while a particular implementation of a method may not use the parameter, knowing its value can help you figure out which stage of a process you are in, especially when you do not have the whole call stack above you.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a macro to suppress the unreferenced formal parameter warning:

```
#define UNUSED( x ) ( &reinterpret_cast< const int& >( x ) )
```

This has the following advantages:

- Unlike #define UNUSED( x ) ( void )x, it doesn't introduce a need for the full definition of the parameter's type to be seen where no such need may have existed before.
- Unlike #define UNUSED( x ) &x, it can be used safely with parameters whose types overload the unary & operator.