# What does "(void)!ptr" do?

Tags: c++

I see it when I read pugixml source code and I really don't know why it's there.

```
void foo(void* ptr) {
    (void)!ptr;  // What does this line do?
}
```

Comment: Looks like a replacement for just leaving the parameter unnamed.

Comment: Usually stops compilers and other tools from complaining about unused parameters by applying a useless operation.

Comment: Related: [Unused parameter in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763937/unused-parameter-in-c11)

Comment: Yes, the "ptr" is used only in assert statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(void)ptr;` is a common way to suppress "unused parameter" warnings, which may be necessary when the function signature is required to contain more parameters than the function uses (e.g. in a callback, if the 'user data' parameter is not used).

The `!` is new to me, though it is superfluous in this context because the return value is just thrown away.

Comment: The ``!`` probably forces an operation so it cannot simply discard the usage.

Comment: To me it seems like unnecessary paranoia. The cast to void is there to make the parameter "seem" used, and every compiler I know of understands this and avoids emitting the unused parameter warning.

Comment: `!` also returns a `bool`. It might avoid a "can't cast pointer to non-integer" warning or something similar. Personally, I'm surprised you can typecast to `void` at all.

Comment: Open Watcom C/C++ 1.9 doesn't get [this one](http://ideone.com/lQ5Wdm) right. It removes the pointer dereference and there's no crash.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone The left operand of the comma operator is implicitly cast to `void` per the C standard.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: you dereferenced an invalid pointer and invoked undefined behaviour. That code isn't required to crash, or in fact do anything sensible. The compiler is justified in optimizing away the dereference.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it wouldn't dereference any pointer in that case, not just NULL.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: Any *valid* dereference would have no side-effects, and any *invalid* dereference would trigger UB. So the compiler can optimize it out. (Note that you never used *`volatile`*).

Comment: A valid dereference of a pointer to a volatile object is a side effect.

Comment: ...you did use `volatile`. Clearly a reading comprehension fail on my part :). So yeah, compiler bug. Probably.

Comment: I just looked at the disassembly of the object file produced from compilation of that single `blah()` function (not of the whole program) and there's only `ret` in the function, so it's a bug.