# unrefrenced formal parameter warning in c++ (visual studio)

Tags: c

In my code there is around 500 "unreferenced formal parameter", I need to suppress them, I got include guards but I need to do it for 5oo times, can anyone suggest the macro to suppress these warnings.

```
(void)status;

hCVar* 
pTmpVar = (hCVar *)pIB;
```

This is one among many.

A macro that can suppress all of them. How can I do so?

Comment: How about just disabling the warning itself?

Comment: `#pragma warning (disable: XXXX)` where XXXX is the number of the warning (I forget what it is). But in C++ you can also remove the parameter name (and just leave the type), that's probably the more correct thing to do.

Comment: can you suggest me in c make ,thank you for suggestion

Comment: @pramodmadinapalli If your question is about C it should be tagged as C not C++. You can't remove the parameter name in C, but the `#pragma` should still work.

Comment: no bro cmake not c language,see i am making my project platform independent by using cmake and needed of macro to disable all this warnings

Comment: Why don't you show a short snippet that triggers the warning and also exactly the warning that you get? Are you writing C or C++ (the tags say C!?)?

Comment: if(MSVC)
add_definitions(-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
add_definitions(-D-Wno-unused-parameter)
add_definitions(-D-Wno-unused-variable)
add_definitions(-D-Wno-unreferenced-formal-parameter)

Comment: this is the way i try to give flags for compiler to suppress,but for unrefrenced formal parameter it is not working

Comment: if(MSVC)
  # Force to always compile with W4
  if(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS MATCHES "/W[0-4]")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "/W[0-4]" "/W4" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
  else()
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /W4")
  endif()
elseif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  # Update if necessary
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wno-long-long -pedantic")
endif()

Comment: Please put relevant stuff into the question, not into comments. `-D-Wno-unused-parameter` defines a macro named `-Wno-unused-parameter` which I bet is not a valid macro name. This looks like you try to emulate a gcc command line, but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As john said:

A solution in the code is to

```
#pragma warning disable(4100)
```

(or other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020584/avoid-warning-unreferenced-formal-parameter?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C138.1909) or `[[maybe_unused]]` in C++17). You can also add `/Wd4100` in the makefile to the compiler command line.